# How do you read multiple entries of xml through VB2010

Tags: xml, vb.net

Ok so here is my totally messed up problem. I need to read through several lines of xml entries to find something i need. "for an example" -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--XML Database.-->
    <Data>
      <Person>
        <Name>hayyo</Name>
        <Email>222@yolo.com</Email>
        <Tel>345</Tel>
      </Person>
      <Person>
        <Name>hihi</Name>
        <Email>666@yolo.com</Email>
        <Tel>665</Tel>
      </Person>
    </Data>
```

j****I now know how to do several lines of xml entries. (win for me)****

```
    Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Dim XmlOut As XmlWriter
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        With XmlOut



            ' Start our first person.
            .WriteStartElement("Person")

            ' The person nodes.
            .WriteStartElement("Name")
            .WriteString(fullName.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()

            .WriteStartElement("Email")
            .WriteString(address.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()

            .WriteStartElement("Tel")
            .WriteString(phoneNum.Text.ToString())
            .WriteEndElement()


            ' The end of this person.
            .WriteEndElement()



        End With

        MessageBox.Show("XML file saved.")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Form2.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
        XmlOut.WriteEndDocument()
        XmlOut.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("XML file ended.")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        ' Initialize the XmlWriter.
        XmlOut = XmlWriter.Create("MyName.xml", settings)

        ' Write the Xml declaration.
        XmlOut.WriteStartDocument()

        ' Write a comment.
        XmlOut.WriteComment("XML Database.")

        ' Write the root element.
        XmlOut.WriteStartElement("Data")

    End Sub
```

However i don't know how to display the entries. 
I just want the names to display. It will only show the last entry right now.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (Search.Text = "") Then

            MessageBox.Show("No file name entered")

        Else

            If (System.IO.File.Exists(Search.Text.ToString())) Then

                Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(Search.Text.ToString())

                While (document.Read())

                    Dim type = document.NodeType

                    If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                        If (document.Name = "Name") Then

                            XmlName.Visible = True
                            XmlName.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                        End If

                        If (document.Name = "Email") Then

                            XmlAddress.Visible = True
                            XmlAddress.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                        End If

                        If (document.Name = "Tel") Then

                            XmlPhone.Visible = True
                            XmlPhone.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                        End If

                    End If

                End While

            Else

                MessageBox.Show("The filename you selected was not found.")

            End If

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also what would I do to search through the xml file to find  hihi  and then pull his phone number in the file and display it.

I know this is not much to go on but i am trying to find out how to search on a small scale, so I can do work later on in a project that will be a big file.

I have just figured out what i need for my future assignment so I am trying to edit an old file to play with it before i go build my assignment.

Just a point in the right direction would be cool.

***Any help is good, even highly advance stuff. That way i can confuse the shit out of the teacher. lol *****

I am still working on this so i might update again. I only got 6 rep so i can't answer my own question yet.

Comment: i am seeing the how almost i just don't know how to get there. 
I got ' The end of this person.
        .WriteEndElement() 
will end the element, but i want to end it and start a new one so it will add on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off by creating an empty console application, put this code in it:

```vb
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <!--XML Database.-->
              <Data>
                <Person>
                  <Name>hayyo</Name>
                  <Email>222@yolo.com</Email>
                  <Tel>345</Tel>
                </Person>
                <Person>
                  <Name>hihi</Name>
                  <Email>666@yolo.com</Email>
                  <Tel>665</Tel>
                </Person>
              </Data>

    Dim p = xml.Root.Descendants("Name") '<----
  End Sub
End Module
```

At this point p will contain a Collection of Name nodes (XElement). Iterate using LINQ or a loop and display as you like.

[image]

In your case you will probably be loading an XML from file so use [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx).

Comment: this looks very complex. I will try this later tonight.

Comment: @HankBates: Complex? I can't imagine how more simple you can get it than just one line of code (+ maybe some extra for the output).

Comment: i don't understand how to use it. just tried poping it into the code i had. because the first page just builds the code in xml and then the second page reads it. I think this would work later on. maybe i am just looking at this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a point in the right direction would be cool.

You can use the xml file as a data source and use LINQ to pull records from it.  There is even a version of LINQ designed for xml.

Alternatively, even though you say the file is large, loading the xml file directly into a datatable, using the methods in the datatable, might be possible and would certainly speed up your searches.

Comment: Well I never heard of LINQ until now. But this is a class project. I guess LINQ would be useful if my college would do something really productive. (In that case I wouldn't be studying VB 2010 ;) lol)
but they want me to use vb and xml only this time. and not really type the xml. I added the second line of that because i know some xml code.

Comment: this is something i will have to investigate later on, after I pass the class. Thanks